# With core.autocrlf=true, why does git log -p show ^M line endings?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

Deleted line does not have this ending. Only the added one.
Am I missing another setting? Is CRLF in the repo?

Commit was created by IDE, I use default git+bash installation on Windows for `git log`.

Comment: Are you the only one committing changes to this file?

Comment: No, but others' commits have this problem too, most likely using similar or the same environment.

Comment: Do other also commit from Windows with autocrlf? And the original commit was from Windows too?